# Put JSON Data on JQuery DataTables

Tags: php, json, datatables

I want to ask how to put JSON Data on JQuery DataTables? I cannot load my JSON data when I want to load it. I am using CodeIgniter.
Here is my code on my view

```
<table id="kategoriTable" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Kode Kategori</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>Definisi</th>
                <th>Unsur Abstrak</th>
                <th>Alias</th>
                <th>Sumber Definisi</th>
                <th>Tanggal</th>
                <th>Tipe Tanggal</th>
                <th>Edisi</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Other Citation Detail</th>
                <th>Katalog</th>
                <th>Organisasi</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

I have tried this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#kategoriTable').dataTable({
    ajax: {
    url : "http://localhost:90/kugi_deployment/api/json/reply/KategoriRetrieve",
    dataSrc : function(json) {
       console.log(json);
       return json.Kategoris
    }
   },
   //data : testData.Kategoris,
   columns: [
  { data: "KodeKategori"},
  { data: "Nama"},
  { data: "Definisi"},
  { data: "UnsurAbstrak"},
  { data: "Alias"},
  { data: "SumberDefinisi"},
  { data: "Tanggal"},
  { data: "TipeTanggal"},
  { data: "Edisi"},
  { data: "Role"},
  { data: "OtherCitationDetail"},
  { data: "NamaKatalog"},
  { data: "NamaOrganisasi"}
 ]
  });
    </script>
```

This is my JSON Data Structure

```
{"State":0,"Message":"","Kategoris":[{"KodeKategori":"A","Nama":"REFERENSI SPASIAL","Definisi":"","UnsurAbstrak":true,"Alias":"","SumberDefinisi":"","Tanggal":"\/Date(-62135596800000-0000)\/","TipeTanggal":"","Edisi":"","Role":"","OtherCitationDetail":"","NamaKatalog":"Katalog Unsur Geografis","NamaOrganisasi":"Badan Informasi Geospasial"}, ....and so on, ]}
```

Last, this is the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $get_url_service = $this->url_service->GetUrl('KategoriRetrieve');
    $get_json = file_get_contents($get_url_service);
    $data['get_data'] = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($get_json, TRUE)), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $this->load->view('test', $data);
}
```

It shows error, cannot parse the data. Here is the screenshot I take:
[image: This is the error in the browser]

When I try to load from that url it returns 'Loading' forever. Am I do something wrong with it? I really confuse to fix this. Hope anyone can help me to fix this. Thanks

Comment: The JSON data is probably serialized as a string, you have to parse it in to a JSON object. Try ```var obj = JSON.parse(text);```

Comment: how do you return the json? your json is invalid too.. run it into a validator

Comment: Well, there is nothing with the JSON nor the initialisation itself -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0ng51ek1/** so it must be something else ...Do you ever get a response at all? Have updated my answer below to 1) console out a response if any, and 2) return the `Kategoris` array directly. Hope it helps!

Comment: @davidkonrad I see. I got error when trying to get the url of the JSON Data. My url to get the data is: `http://localhost:90/kugi_deployment/api/json/reply/KategoriRetrieve`
When I tried to get the data, response from JSON is error. I have updated my question above, showing the error

Comment: It seems to me that you never get a response at all - why not try just to echo the `$get_json` out, as below? That part seems to work fine, guess that it is the result of `file_get_contents($get_url_service)` you have as demo JSON above?

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes, I see. But why the property `url` did not get the url I want? It is loading forever. It was success when I tried your code on JSFiddle. But when I want to get the JSON from web service, it is loading forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
public function index()
{
    $get_url_service = $this->url_service->GetUrl('KategoriRetrieve');
    $get_json = file_get_contents($get_url_service);
    echo $get_json;
    //what are the below lines good for??
    //$data['get_data'] = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($get_json, TRUE)), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    //$this->load->view('test', $data);
}
```

---

You have it a little bit backwards. You must instruct dataTables to use items from the `Kategoris` array, this is done through `ajax.dataSrc`. And `columns` should specify which `data`-property in each item from the array that corresponds to which column :

```js
$('#kategoriTable').dataTable({
   ajax: {
        url : "<?php echo base_url().'json/reply/KategoriRetrieve' ?>",
        dataSrc : function(json) {
           console.log(json);
           return json.Kategoris
        }
   },
   columns: [
      { data: "KodeKategori"},
      { data: "Nama"},
      { data: "Definisi"},
      { data: "UnsurAbstrak"},
      { data: "Alias"},
      { data: "SumberDefinisi"},
      { data: "Tanggal"},
      { data: "TipeTanggal"},
      { data: "Edisi"},
      { data: "Role"},
      { data: "OtherCitationDetail"},
      { data: "NamaKatalog"},
      { data: "NamaOrganisasi"}
   ]
});
```

Comment: I still got error when trying to load the data. It is loading forever. I have edited my code above @davidkonrad